# Laravel serve can't have access except Main page (index) via LAN

Tags: laravel

I have a little problem (I think).
When I do PHP artisan serve I can access to my project:

```
http://MY_IP_HERE:PORT
```

But only the index page!

Problem:
When I click on a link I lose my IP and get the URL:

example:

```
http://project.test/admin
```

(so they can't open the page).
It should be:

```
http://MY_IP_HERE:PORT/admin
```

How can I fix it? (if there is a solution) the point of this is,
I want to serve (host) a project to my network (LAN) so me and my friends can have access to it, the project is on a W10 with laravel homestead.
If need more/specific info just tell me and I will answer!

Is this a good option or should I do something else?

Comment: If in your .env APP_URL is correctly set to the IP address, you have to run the command `php artisan serve --port=YOUR_PORT`. If that doesn't work, your local server is not accessible in the network.

Comment: If you are using Homestead then you will need to map the folder and add sites or projects.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey i have this: APP_URL=http://192.168.1.87:8000
but i can access the main page
image: https://prnt.sc/l91x0m
but when i click on admin:
image: http://prntscr.com/l91xmu

Comment: @sachinkumar how?

Comment: Change it to `APP_URL=192.168.1.87` and run `php artisan serve --port=8000`

Comment: if i do serve only i got this ip
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
but still not working

Comment: The problem is solved! it was an error on code, when i use the route i had "project.test/"SOMETHING", so i set a name to the route and fix it!

Comment: Visit this link may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070043/how-to-map-project-directory-in-homestead-yaml-using-relative-path